# New / Upload page buttons not shown

Tags: divshot

Signed up to have a go at Divshot today, however there is a wee problem.

[image: Missing upload/new page buttons]

It showed a 403 in the console for
https://s3.amazonaws.com/projects.divshot.com/?prefix=XXXXXX/welcome/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this happened! If you're still having difficulties could you email support@divshot.com so we can help you sort this out? Once in awhile new accounts with brand new projects will run into this issue and refreshing the application usually does the trick. We directly connect to Amazon S3 to host your projects and there could have been a slight delay in assigning permissions / validating credentials. Thank you!